# Why is two finger scrolling behaving differently on two separate ipads?

Tags: ipad, safari, dojo, scroll, touch

We're currently working on an iPad version of our web application at work.  We are seeing inconsistent behavior with regards to two-finger scrolling on scrollable areas within others scrollable areas across two iPads. Both devices are iPad2 models.

On one device, dojo grids and trees require one finger to scroll.  On the other, they require two fingers to scroll.  On both devices Safari is being used to view the website.

What could cause this behavior?  Is there some setting we haven't discovered that dictates whether you need to use 1 or 2 fingers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a difference in IOS versions (one is on 4, the other on 5).

Comment: Yup, [iOS 5 added one-finger scrolling](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5) to Mobile Safari.  You can also enable inertial scrolling using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that

-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch is not the same as one-finger scrolling enabled by iOS5.

-webkit-overflow-scrolling uses the iPad's built in functionality (the touch acceleration and bounce). However, if the contents in your div change, or you manually move the contents inside the div (ie you made your own div scrollbar and are scrolling the contents), enabling this will mess things up. What it will do is make the "top" of the scroll able div wherever it happens to be located. What does this mean? If your contents are scrolled half way down and then you add new content to the div, with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch, the very top of the touch-scroll area will be half way down your div. You will not be able touch-scroll back to the top.